# Could not start orderer with ca file generated by ca server in fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I start ca server with the test code in fabric-ca-sdk(fabric-sdk-java/fabric-sdk-java/src/test/fixture/sdkintegration).and use fabric sdk to enroll an orderer and get the  ca file from the response. and then I put the ca file to the first network demo, and use

> docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d

to start order, but failed, the log is:

> Failed to initialize local MSP: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.example.com")

I use openssl to check the pem file generated by ca server.There is no any problem about the file. Please help me if you know the reason about the 
question. Thank you soooooooo much.
the ca.example.com-cer.pem file information is below:

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        03:b1:1d:83:1e:86:57:f6:8f:0c:e1:d1:e9:84:14:0d
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
    Issuer: C=US, ST=California, L=San Francisco, O=example.com, CN=ca.example.com
    Validity
        Not Before: Feb 25 12:43:29 2018 GMT
        Not After : Feb 23 12:43:29 2028 GMT
    Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=San Francisco, O=example.com, CN=ca.example.com
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
        EC Public Key:
            pub: 
                04:8f:70:81:96:e6:4c:c7:f5:c0:38:2d:4f:aa:35:
                ea:1f:00:f5:a9:cd:93:69:44:93:ac:d2:89:34:e7:
                ca:b1:73:34:3c:c3:28:3e:43:71:79:9b:a4:ce:5b:
                e2:a6:57:6d:53:cf:9f:5d:52:c0:81:a7:73:a5:d8:
                be:8e:6f:a8:3f
            ASN1 OID: prime256v1
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
            2.5.29.37.0
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
            19:B5:15:37:90:85:4D:AE:85:0A:0F:94:15:70:FC:3C:56:9B:87:87:23:93:3A:D5:A9:C3:19:D2:93:F2:D4:92
Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
    30:44:02:20:6a:f2:74:ab:b3:2c:fe:ff:20:2d:d9:fa:b9:3a:
    54:46:43:cd:a7:f7:78:ff:a3:de:e2:7c:c0:b3:e5:6f:76:e8:
    02:20:50:47:1d:ba:50:64:a3:a0:06:fc:70:a8:bc:95:2c:08:
    5a:91:c5:e6:d2:b0:99:43:2e:52:fb:dd:e2:51:5a:d6
```

and the orderer.example.com-cert.pem file is:

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        2c:35:e7:3e:37:73:08:80:18:66:47:df:34:63:dc:0b:f4:44:b0:c0
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
    Issuer: C=US, ST=California, L=San Francisco, O=example.com, CN=ca.example.com
    Validity
        Not Before: Jun 20 09:02:00 2018 GMT
        Not After : Jun 20 09:07:00 2019 GMT
    Subject: OU=orderer, CN=order.example.com
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
        EC Public Key:
            pub: 
                04:73:48:ae:95:c5:60:fd:c3:4c:94:61:98:97:18:
                62:24:2f:bb:7e:e7:ad:02:10:15:78:12:6e:24:f2:
                2f:33:8f:24:db:16:25:c7:9f:94:a4:e3:9c:10:0d:
                11:d2:80:e9:f7:ff:e8:69:48:1a:85:65:b9:22:7e:
                0a:b2:dc:26:d5
            ASN1 OID: prime256v1
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:FALSE
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
            F0:26:72:32:C2:24:F0:DE:9E:C5:1C:11:7D:01:BD:96:16:62:C1:0E
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
            keyid:19:B5:15:37:90:85:4D:AE:85:0A:0F:94:15:70:FC:3C:56:9B:87:87:23:93:3A:D5:A9:C3:19:D2:93:F2:D4:92

        1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1: 
            {"attrs":{"hf.Affiliation":"","hf.EnrollmentID":"order.example.com","hf.Type":"orderer"}}
Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
    30:45:02:21:00:d9:87:88:6c:a0:2c:6d:80:c2:e3:6d:0f:b1:
    26:b4:5e:24:02:24:6b:42:6f:16:72:7d:f0:eb:a9:e0:28:a4:
    99:02:20:5f:4c:5b:57:28:96:55:ab:3f:55:07:1c:75:df:a7:
    49:5e:90:5d:05:7c:b2:f8:e0:79:69:9d:d4:aa:6a:60:a1
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of previous builds.
Docker volumes are not deleted with `docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml down` and for an unknown reason some times docker mounts old volumes with certificates.
So, deleting volumes will help.
do: `docker volume prune`
WARNING: this command will delete all docker volumes.

Comment: Probabaly you did nothing wrong BUT something left in previous volumes when you used bynf before. So removing docker volumes gives you clean system